# How do I connect to a secure cluster from YAML pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

That's it. Plain and simple.

The first step in my pipeline is to remove services that are no longer supported. To do that I need to use [Connect-ServiceFabricCluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/connect-servicefabriccluster?view=azureservicefabricps) to connect to the cluster. But that requires a certificate installed on the local machine. I won't have a local machine in a hosted pipeline and I have a problem with installing the certificate on the hosted VM for security reasons.

So how do I connect?

Comment: You need to work with the admi. To get the cert in place on the hosted VM , it is kind of prerequisite ...It may take some time though .

Comment: But the Hosted VM will disappear each time so there is no "get the cert in place". Also, I'm wary of installing a secure cert on a VM that might be reused by someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1,

Dont know if you tried azure cli `sfctl cluster select` which allows you to specify a certificate, check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-sfctl) for more information.

In order to use the certificate in your pipeline. You need to go to the **Library** under **Pipelines** and click secure files and add your certificate from local. Make sure **Authorize for use in all pipelines** is checked when adding your certificate.
[image]

Then you can add a **Download secure file** task to download your certificate in your pipeline.

Then you can consume it in your next task by referring to the download location "$(Agent.TempDirectory)\yourcertificatefilename", check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/secure-files?view=azure-devops) for more information

```
sfctl cluster select --endpoint https://testsecurecluster.com:19080 --cert "$(Agent.TempDirectory)\yourcertificatefilename" --key ./keyfile.key
```

2,

If above `sfctl cluster select` is not working, You can install the certificate which is already uploaded with a powershell task to the hosted agent

```
Import-Certificate -FilePath ""$(Agent.TempDirectory)\yourcertificatefilename"" -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\Root
```

3,

If the hosted agent has security concern. You can create your own self-hosted agent on your local machine. You can then install the certificate in your on-premises agent. 
To create self-hosted agent.

You need to get a PAT and assign the scope to **Agent Pool**. click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops) for detailed steps. You will need the PAT to config your self-hosted agent later.

Then go to **Project setting,** select **Agent Pools** under **Pipelines**, Create a self-defined agent pool if you donot have one, Then select your agent pool, click new agent, and follow the steps to create your own agent.
[image]

Hope above can be helpful to you!

Comment: Rather than a hosted agent I can simply remove the certificate.
$Certs = get-childitem cert:"CurrentUser\My"
$Certs | %{Remove-Item -path $_.PSPath -recurse -Force}